# When creating a table in Oracle SQL, how can I create a column that will contain specific values?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I am trying to create a table and one of the columns will contain file names like 2009-00014 or 2013-55045.
Should it be 'number' or 'varchar'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphen requires that the column be a string.  In Oracle, the recommended type would be `varchar2()`, with a specified length.

In addition, the names of files might one day include other characters -- who knows how an application will change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be varchar2.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, you can use 'varchar2' but If you're going to do mathematical operations on that column you should 'number'